# How to export arm64 and x86-64 binary into one?

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, decompilation, ghidra

I am trying to export a binary that contains both AARCH64-64 and x86-64 in Ghidra. I only opened the x86-64 counterpart to perform some changes.

When I tried to export it, it exported a .bin file that I can't replace with the original Mach-O universal binary. How do I go about exporting the patched x86-64 as one universal binary in Ghidra?

Original Binary:

[image]

Exported x86-64 Binary:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems like you are effectively running into the same issue as this question: [How to export a working elf binary from Ghidra?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20877/how-to-export-a-working-elf-binary-from-ghidra)

Ghidra doesn't export working ELF/PE/Mach-O files when you export something. You have to use an existing proper exporter to get a patched binary. I am not aware of one for Mach-O, especially not Mach-O with multiple architectures, but it might still be possible to write a minimal one for your use case.